# Errata for Semigroups and Combinatorial Applications by G. Lallement?

Tags: reference-request, semigroups

I am asking this question after years of frustration with the typos
in the subject book I have read. It has been cited and referenced by many literatures and books in math and computer science. However, there are many typos, at least in the
copy I own -1979 edition 1st printing.

The fact that it has been used by many researchers lead me to believe
that there might be an Errata either published or circulated. But, I
cannot find it anywhere on Internet. My question is

> Does anybody know an errata for the subject book exists? If so,
>   where and how can I get it?

Thank you.

Comment: Scaaahu, please don't bump your posts without adding to them or correcting them. Other people also have their questions waiting for answers. I know how unpleasant it is when no one even comments on your question -- it's happened to me more than once. But if nobody has any idea about the answer or wants to answer, what can be done about it?

Comment: @ymar, I apologize. My explanation is the time zone. I live in Asia(Taiwan). I was afraid the time I posted this question was not rigtht for the readers in other areas.

Answer (score 3):

Th proof of The Prime Decomposition Theorem (Krohn-Rhodes Theorem) in Lallement's book is slightly flawed, but a correction was published shortly afterwards [I should give credit to John Rhodes and Ben Steinberg for pointing out this reference in their book]:

G. Lallement, Augmentations and wreath products of monoids, *Semigroup Forum*, **21** (1980) 89-90. DOI 10.1007/BF02572539

I don't think a list of typos of Lallement's book has been ever published.