# Recommend a semigroup theory book.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation, semigroups

I have learnt semigroup theory and I want some good book for studying by myself. Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Given your profile, I guess you want to study the algebraic theory of semigroups. A good place to start is

[1] P. A. Grillet, Semigroups, An Introduction to the Structure Theory, Marcel Dekker, Inc., New York, 1995.

The following book is slightly more advanced, but contains some interesting material

[2] P. Higgins, Techniques of Semigroup Theory, World Scientific, 1999.

You may also try

[3] G. Lallement, Semigroups and Combinatorial Applications, Wiley and Sons, 1979.

Comment: And how about Howie's book : Fundamental of Semigroup Theory and A.H.  Preston, G.B. Clifford The Algebraic Theory of Semigroups, Mathematical Surveys, No. 7  1961 ? Which one I should start first?

Comment: I would keep A.H. Preston and G.B. Clifford as a reference book, once you know enough theory to be able to skip some details.  Howie's book is more elementary and contains less material than Grillet's, but you may prefer that to start with. It's a matter of taste !

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Since you recommend Lallement's book, would you take a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/138846/17111). Thanks.